# Нормальный html редактор для linux

Tags: html, linux, веб-программирование, вёрстка

*Пробовал bluefish - оказался слишком тормознутый*

Ищу нормальный HTML редактор для вёрстки. Критерии:

1. Настраиваемая подсветка синтаксиса
2. Поддержка вкладок
3. Наличие слева столбца, который бы показывал номер строчки

OS - linux mint

Comment: Написанные требования вообще практически любой редактор скорее умеет, чем нет. Изкоробочные gedit или kate, например, полностью подходят под запрос.

Comment: @danpetruk, только nano - только хардкор)

Comment: Ой, случайно нажал переоткрыть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

geany, все есть.. еще и теги закроет за вас ))

Answer (score 17):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Comment: Total: USD $59 фи..

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov - он условно платный, единственное что, изредка, будет надоедать окошко с просьбой о покупке

Answer (score 8):

Подождите, подождите, vim же!

Answer (score 7):

Vim, Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 4):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/)

> Aptana Studio — кроссплатформенная, свободная, интегрированная среда разработки приложений (IDE) c открытым исходным кодом для создания динамических веб-приложений. Включает в себя такие функции как автодополнение набираемых конструкций на лету для кода JavaScript, HTML, и CSS, выделение цветом JavaScript, HTML и CSS кода, предупреждения об ошибках и возможность для настройки и расширения пользовательского интерфейса.
> С помощью дополнительных плагинов Aptana Studio также поддерживает разработку для следующих языков и платформ: Ruby on Rails, PHP, Python, Adobe Air и Apple iPhone.
>
> Последняя версия Aptana Studio включает в себя сервер Jaxer, позволяющий выполнять JavaScript на стороне сервера. А также интегрирована с сервисом Aptana Cloud, который предлагает лёгкое развёртывание и хостинг веб-приложений на серверах cloud computing компании Aptana с возможностью мгновенной масштабируемости ресурсов по требованию. Данный хостинг поддерживает следующие платформы: PHP 5, Jaxer, Ruby on Rails и Java, в ближайшее время ожидается поддержка веб-приложений на Python.

Answer (score 4):

Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 3):

Kodomo Edit
сам юзаю, крутая вещь.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse, а также в Krusader'е есть отличный встроеный редактор.

Answer (score 2):

[Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=ru&option=php)

Comment: оно еще тормознутее bluefish, причем в разы

Answer (score 1):

Если чисто html, то Komodo Edit - быстрый и удобный
Если ещё и php, то NetBeans IDE - более медленный(java), но в нём самая умная и удобная выдача подсказок какую я встречал. Достойный конкурент разве что phpDisigner(под Windows)

---

Gedweb

Comment: Боюсь вы не пользовались Webstorm

Comment: а Вы не бойтесь, пробывал. ИМХО перегружен, к тому же НЕ СОВСЕМ FREE. За что мне и понравился NetBeans, что я смог выключить уйму лишних подсказок.
Кому-то нравится Eclipse или Zend(на базе того же eclipse), мне же они не подходят.
Автор спросил, я ответил. Есть свои предложения - пишите, а не коментируйте чужие